# [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"]

Tags: apache-flex, jsp, flex4, tomcat6

I am trying to display database details in a Flex datagrid and connected using HTTP Service. It was able to display details without any issue when I was working in the FlashBuilder 4.5, however, I deployed the bin-debug part in the Tomcat webserver to access it globally.

I am experiencing this error message when I am trying to access the swf file "**HTTP request error Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"]. URL: http://localhost:8084/UA/details.jsp"**

I tried to create the crossdomain.xml file and deployed in the root directory but still experiencing the same error.

Here is my crossdomain.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>  
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Can any one help me out ?

Regards,

Serenity

Comment: Does your Tomcat located on localhost?

Comment: No, I manually installed Tomcat server with port number 8084

Comment: Where did your install it? On other computer? On production server or on the same computer? Which URL do you use to access it with web browser?

Comment: I installed in the same computer and able to access the swf file, however, getting the error message because the Datagrid is trying to pull the details from the database.

Comment: Try to access to http://localhost:8084/UA/details.jsp from browser. Is this JSP available?

Comment: I am able to retrieve the details with the help of JSP, it's working fine without any issue

Comment: Ok, I haven't any other suggestions at the moment :(

Comment: Is this error a runtime error thrown from the Flash Player?  Or is it some other type of error?  Is SWF recognized as a mime-type on the server?  I'm not sure of the default configuration options for Tomcat's web server.

Comment: I fixed the error by adding the following lines in the coding part :   private function preinit():void 
   {
    Security.loadPolicyFile("http://localhost:8084/UA/crossdomain.xml");
   }

Comment: And also added <s:Application ................preinitialize="preinit()" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked permissions on all involved files? 
Are you sure the user running your 'application' has at least read permissions for the file?